# Upgrading NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, websocket

I hope this is not too much to ask.

Im new to this NodeJS tech, which I think is amazing, but Im not a really good programmer, I found this awesome example http://softwareas.com/video-sync-with-websocket-and-node/, but I cant make it work. I believe the code its outdated, and Im running the latest Node, I've been trying to fix it but I cant get near close.
I dont fully understand how websockets work, and is giving me a headache.

When I run the server it runs just fine.

```
var sys = require("util");
var ws = require('websocket-server');
var userCount = [];

var server = ws.createServer({
  debug: true
});

server.addListener("connection", function(conn){
  server.broadcast("userCount " + ++userCount);
  conn.addListener("message", function(message){
    server.broadcast(message);
  });
});

server.addListener("close", function(conn){
  server.broadcast("userCount " + --userCount);
});

server.listen(8000, "localhost");
function log(msg) {
  sys.puts(+new Date + ' - ' + msg.toString());
};
```

But when I interact with the client (Log as a user) the server crashes and I get this error in the console, and I've no idea what it means.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLlga.png
I'm really new to this, and I don't understand D:, any help is really appreciated

Comment: websocket-server is not a public npm module, how did you install it?

Comment: How do you "log as a user"? Could you post the exact request? I tried to do a GET to localhost:8000 but the request appears to hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package 'websocket-server' is unmaintained for 4 years, you should consider using another one.

There have been several forks in github, https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server/network, but with few changes more, so they are almost same obsolete.

Trying the examples in the package, https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server/tree/master/test/manual, the echo-server.js (very similar to your code) doesn't work, server hangs (or appears to hang), with no traces. If you try chat-server.js it does work, but I don't know if it does what you need/want.

You can run those examples with command:

```
node test/manual/chat-server.js
```

Double check if there is a newer module that does the same :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, The chat-server its not what I need, but yea I'll search for a newer websocket module.

Comment: I've found this one https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node. Is there an easy way to make the transition